Encountering Error When Accessing GraphQL Playground in Sitecore
During the setup of GraphQL on my local environment, I've made all the necessary configuration changes and enabled the Master endpoint. However, when attempting to access the Playground via the following link: https://local-site/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui, I'm encountering an 'Authentication Required' error. How can I resolve this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem, add more details about your configuration and the problem you experience. As it's currently written, it's hard to reproduce the issue and provide recommendations.

To address this issue, you'll need to update the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config file to incorporate site-neutral paths.
To do this, navigate to the Sitecore installation directory, typically located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[SC folder]\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.
Here, locate and modify the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config file. Within the configuration file, locate the siteNeutralPaths node and append the path /sitecore/api/graph/items/ to it.
Once you've added the path, save your changes to the file.

Once you've completed these configuration adjustments, please visit a URL:
https://localsite.com/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui
Alternate Approach
Alternatively, you can navigate to the /App_Config/Sitecore/Services.GraphQL folder and locate the Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config file.
Within this file, you'll find the requireAuthentication tag, set it to false.


You may need to make configuration changes to the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config file to allow site neutral path.
Try these steps to solve this issue.

Go to Sitecore installation folder. In my case, it is C:\inetpub\wwwroot[SC installation folder name]\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\
You will see Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config. Open the configuration file for editing.
Search for the siteNeutralPaths in the file
Under this node, add the path /sitecore/api/graph/items
Save the changes

For the graphical presentation follow this.
Hope this will solve your issue.

Even if you are logged in to the Sitecore admin portal, you may encounter the message “Authentication required” when browsing your Sitecore instance URL.

1.To resolve this issue, you need to modify the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config file to include site-neutral paths.
2.To add a site-neutral path to the Owin authentication config file, go to the Sitecore installation folder, which in this case is located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot[SC installed folder]\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.
3.Here, you will find the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Config file that you need to edit.
4.In the configuration file, search for the “siteNeutralPaths” node, and add the path “/sitecore/api/graph/items/” underneath it. Once you have added the path, save the changes to the file.

After you have finished making the configuration changes, please access the URL something like below.
https://sc10localcm.dev.local/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui
You can try and execute the below query as shown in image and see that everything works as expected.
you need to take care of two things as shown in bellow image.
1.In QUARY VARIABLE section you need to pass contextItem path
2.In HTTP HEADERS section you need to pass your API key
query GQLQuerySamples($contextItem: String!) {
  item(path: $contextItem) {
    children {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}


That’s all! You are all set to start using GraphQL to query your data.
Hope this helps!!!

Check the security ref in the configuration is pointing to publicService as below.
<sitecore>
    <api>
        <GraphQL>
            <endpoints>
                <master url="/sitecore/api/graph/items/master" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.GraphQLEndpoint, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true">
                    <url>$(url)</url>
                    <enabled role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enabled>
                    <enableSubscriptions>true</enableSubscriptions>
                    <!-- lock down the endpoint when deployed to content delivery -->
                    <graphiql role:require="ContentDelivery">false</graphiql>
                    <enableSchemaExport role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableSchemaExport>
                    <enableStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableStats>
                    <enableCacheStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableCacheStats>
                    <disableIntrospection role:require="ContentDelivery">true</disableIntrospection>
                    <schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
                        <!-- defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config -->
                        <content ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/content/schemaProviders/systemContent" param1="master" />
                    </schema>
                    <!-- Determines the security of the service. Defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config -->
                    <security ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/publicService" />
                    <!-- Determines how performance is logged for the service. Defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config -->
                    <performance ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/performance/standard" />
                    <!--
                        Cache improves the query performance by caching parsed queries.
                        It is also possible to implement query whitelisting by implementing an authoritative query cache;
                        WhitelistingGraphQLQueryCache is an example of this, capturing queries to files in open mode and allowing only captured queries in whitelist mode.
                    -->
                    <cache type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.QueryTransformation.Caching.GraphQLQueryCache, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost">
                        <param desc="name">$(url)</param>
                        <param desc="maxSize">10MB</param>
                    </cache>

                    <!-- 
                        Extenders allow modifying schema types after they are created by a schema provider but before they are added to the final schema.
                        This is useful when you want to _extend_ a generated schema, for example, to add external API
                        data onto the item API, or to add in custom internal data (e.g. custom layout data to power an app)
                        without having to modify a schema provider directly.
                    
                        Extenders must derive from SchemaExtender.
                    -->
                    <extenders hint="list:AddExtender">
                    </extenders>
                </master>
            </endpoints>
        </GraphQL>
    </api>
</sitecore>

Thereafter you can pass the api key in the header as below. It would give you the desired output.

Hope this helps!!!
